# Practical applications of eigenanalysis

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have always wondered: what are practical applications of finding (and using) **eigenvalues** and **eigenvectors** of matrices?

I'm asking because i studied this at school, and at the time these things were completely abstract entities. Then I did some research, and found their geometrical interpretation, which is now very clear to me (even the Wikipedia page is extremely clear on this topic).

However, what is still not clear to me is: in which fields of application can these derived information become handy, and how? Can some expert list a few notable examples of eigenanalysis applications, or a nice book on the subject that contains such examples (which i attempted to find without success)?

thanks!

Comment: Possible that there is no book offering a complete overview of the uses of eigen analysis and svd?

Answer (score 4):

Have you heard of a little website called Google? Eigenvectors are used to rank pages. [See here.](http://www.rose-hulman.edu/~bryan/googleFinalVersionFixed.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting, and i did not know about that.. Still, one application only..

Answer (score 1):

Also you can determine the eigenfrequency of buildings and bridges for example. You could destroy a bridge by hopping on it with the eigenfrequency and cause resonance - if it wasn't a well built bridge ;-) See for example [this bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacoma_Narrows_Bridge_%281940%29)  or more famous [this bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Bridge,_London).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/MathDrama/reading/Wigner.html

This explains why it was so useful in Quantum Physics, and why it actually was rather unexpected.

But I think it was originally meant to analyze stability of solutions to differential equations.  And hence the other answer concerning bridges.